# Java android REST Api login

Tags: java, android, json, android-ion

I have a endpoint which look like this in SOAPI : 
[image]

And I try to login there in android: I did this :

```
Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
        .load("https://mobile.***.net.pl:447/***MobileProxy/proxy/sessions")
        .setBodyParameter("company", "TEST")
        .setBodyParameter("user", "pawelo")
        .setBodyParameter("secure_password", "8ce241e1ed84937ee48322b170b9b18c")
        .setBodyParameter("secure_device_id", "8ce241e1ed84937ee48322b170b9b18c")
        .asString()
        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {


            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {

                Log.e("TAG " , result);
            }

        });
```

But I don't have a result ok In console I have :

```
04-24 05:58:23.122 24296-24296/rest.hello.org.testrestapi E/TAG: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 (Debian) - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Unsupported Media Type</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.56 (Debian)</h3></body></html>
```

How I can login use this endpoint and when is success this method return Http status and also a json :

```
{
   "sctoken": "437973af-a372d319-9e57-492e-bdaf-2f5152d8624f",
   "tms":    [
            {
         "name": " MapCenterCache",
         "url": "http://cache2.***.net.pl/cache_2015/element?s=%zoom%&x=%x%&y=%y%"
      },
            {
         "name": "OSM Mapnik",
         "url": "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/%zoom%/%x%/%y%.png"
      },
            {
         "name": "OSM1",
         "url": "http://51.254.61.18:8104/tile/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/osm_server_elte/%zoom%/%x%/%y%.png"
      },
            {
         "name": "Mapa",
         "url": "http://mapa.***.net.pl/tms/%zoom%/%x%/%y%.png"
      }
   ],
   "
```

edit :

```
JsonObject json1 = new JsonObject();
    json1.addProperty("company", "TEST");
    json1.addProperty("user", "pawelo");
    json1.addProperty("secure_password", "8ce241e1ed84937ee48322b170b9b18c");
    json1.addProperty("secure_device_id", "8ce241e1ed84937ee48322b170b9b18c");


Ion.with(getApplicationContext())
        .load("https://mobile.***.net.pl:447/SmokMobileProxy/proxy/sessions")
        .setJsonObjectBody(json1)
        .asString()
        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {


            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {

            }

        });

new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a Raw Json using Koush/Ion in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964417/how-to-send-a-raw-json-using-koush-ion-in-android)

Comment: You're missing Content Type and you're not posting JSON with those methods

Comment: @cricket_007 I edit my post but now I have this :

Comment: But i don't know how I can read a answert from server

Comment: Did you try doing anything with `String result`? Put some code there to handle the response from the server :)

Comment: Note: You shouldn't need an Asynctask with Ion library

Comment: Anyway, there's several JSON  examples in the documentation, so I'm not sure why you didn't start with that https://github.com/koush/ion/blob/master/README.md